# How to use an index to read multiple files at a time?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, paste

I want R to read the five files with names like

"alpha_rarefaction_8000_0.txt" ... "alpha_rarefaction_12000_0.txt"

and write it as

"alpha8000" ... "alpha12000", respectively.

I used the following code, but it did not work. Please help. What's wrong with my codes?

I tried to search like "**how to use index in R function**" or "**how to write executable loop in R**", but nothing helps. What kind of search strategy should I use to get effective results where searching the answers on Google?

```
for(i in seq(8000,12000,by=1000)) {
    paste("rare",i,sep="")<-read.table(paste("alpha_rarefaction",i,"0.txt",sep="_"))
}
```

or

```
read.rare<-function(i){
  paste("rare",$i,sep="")<-read.table(paste("alpha_rarefaction",$i,"0.txt",sep="_"))
}
i<-seq(8000,12000,by=1000)
read.rare(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you read the files into a list, possibly doing it this way -

```
## create the sequence for the file names
s <- 8:12 * 1e3
# [1]  8000  9000 10000 11000 12000

## create the full file names from the sequence above
files <- sprintf("alpha_rarefaction_%d_0.txt", s)
# [1] "alpha_rarefaction_8000_0.txt"  "alpha_rarefaction_9000_0.txt" 
# [3] "alpha_rarefaction_10000_0.txt" "alpha_rarefaction_11000_0.txt"
# [5] "alpha_rarefaction_12000_0.txt"

## Now we can loop the file names, reading the data into a list
## and setting the names for each element
datalist <- setNames(lapply(files, read.table), paste0("alpha", s))
```

This will keep all the data frames in a list, which will make working with them later a lot easier.  You can access them individually with the `$` operator.  They have names

```
names(datalist)
[1] "alpha8000"  "alpha9000"  "alpha10000" "alpha11000" "alpha12000"
```

so `datalist$alpha9000`, for example, accesses the second data set (and alternatively with `datalist[[2]]`).

Comment: That's great. I think you not only give me the right answers, but also provide me the right way of thinking in programming. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ming - happy to help.  If this answer works for you, you can click the grey check-mark to accept it.

Comment: of course, it helps a lot. I just got to know that I can accept it in that way. Thanks a lot.